# 'Storage' is not defined on JSHint

Tags: javascript, jquery, storage, jshint

I'm checking my code with JSHint and I found the following problem that I can't resolve.
(im using jQuery.js)

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {  
'Storage' is not defined.  
Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {  
'Storage' is not defined.



Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
};

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
};
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare Storage as a [global](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) for JSHint. Add

> ```
> /*global Storage*/
> ```

on the beggining of your file, or with the rest of your JSHint configuration